# How to include REST API with SPL_AUTOLOAD?

Tags: php, autoload

Im trying to create an autoloader but in my class (named: **Invoice**) I need to add a framework (REST API named **APIclient**) where is more require statements in the code and Im getting `"Warning: include_once(): Failed opening for inclusion"` errors.

So first I created a class in /App/Orders/ with filename Invoice.php

```
<?php
namespace APP\Orders;

use APP\Config;
use APP\Orders\DataValidator;
use APP\Orders\Products;
use APP\DataBase;
use APP\LogErrors;

class Invoice {

    private $config;
    private $PDO;
    
    public function __construct(){
        $this->config = new Config;
        $this->PDO = (new DataBase)->DB_CONN();
        $apiSF = new APIclient("XYZ", "XYZ"); //This is the REST API I WANT TO INCLUDE
    }
}
?>
```

All the classes (objects) loads fine except the Rest API class (**APIclient**) what is need to require Requests.php file.

Here is my autoloader in requests/index.php file:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function($path){
    include_once dirname(__DIR__, 2) . "/" . str_replace("\\", '/', $path) . '.php';
});
?>
```

In the Rest API file (**APIclient.php**) what I want to include have more require statement in the code:

```
if (!class_exists('Requests')) {
    require_once('Requests.php');
}
```

And thats why my autoloader doesn't work.

So in short I want to include a REST API with autoloader where is an another request statement.

I tried to require the REST API file inside the Invoice.php file but also no luck. The REST API file location is:

```
"APP/API/APIclient/APIclient.php"
```

And the way how I tried to include:

```
new \APP\API\APIclient\APIclient("XYZ", "XYZ"); //This is the REST API I WANT TO INCLUDE
```

The autoloader found the APIclient.php file and included fine but failed to open the Requests.php file what is required inside in the APIclient.php.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Here is my folder structure:

```
ROOT:
│   
├───APP
│   ├───API
│   │   └───APIclient
│   │           APIclient.php
│   │           Requests.php
│   │           
│   └───Orders
│           Invoice.php
│           
└───requests
    └───Orders
            createInvoice.php
```

And I recreated the error without my class methods just to make the code more readable.

So the content of the files:

APIclient.php:

```
if (!class_exists('Requests')) {
    require_once('Requests.php');
}

class APIclient {
        
  protected
  $email,
  $apikey;
    
 public function __construct($email, $apikey)
 {
     //Requests::register_autoloader();
     $this->email      = $email;
     $this->apikey     = $apikey;
 }
        
}
```

Requests.php

```
class Requests {
    
}
```

Invoice.php

```
namespace APP\Orders;
class Invoice {
    
    public function __construct(){
        $apiSF = new \APP\API\APIclient\APIclient("XYZ", "XYZ"); 
    }
    
    public function someFunction(){
        return "hello there";
    }
    
}
```

createInvoice.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function($path){
    include_once dirname(__DIR__, 2) . "/" . str_replace("\\", '/', $path) . '.php';
});


use APP\Orders\Invoice;

echo $invoice = (new Invoice())->someFunction();
```

In the API folder (where goes all the API files) I just dont want to change the code and give namespace for the REST API if its possible.

Comment: Edit: The autoloader trying to locate the Requests.php file inside the folder where is index.php (the autoloader itself)

Comment: Does anything change if you do `require_once(__DIR__. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'Requests.php');` ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the autoloader is still trying to open the Requests.php file inside the  requests folder (where is the index.php and the autoloader). But I noticed even if I delete the require statement from the APIclient.php file the autoloader is still trying to locate the Requests.php file (in the requests folder) because there is an  if (!class_exists('Requests')) statement

Comment: I think if you place the files in the correct places and follow the PSR-4 suggestion it will work. Please check again the namespace declaration in the files and define every used class in the use block after the namespace declaration.

Comment: We would need your project structure to debug further.

Comment: In your autoloader, assign the path to a variable a dump it out before requiring it so that you can inspect it. Also, remember that your autoloader will run for _all_ code that needs to be looked up, including code that might not be yours, so you might want to perform some logic to test only for code, along with possibly some `file_exists` tests

Comment: I just added a new answer to this question where I have all the files including the file structure in my project. Thank you!

Comment: Neither `APIclient.php` nor `Requests.php` contain a proper namespace. Why do you load it through `\APP\API\APIclient\APIclient`, but haven't added these classes to that namespace?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you for your answer, because its a third party API and I dont want to make any change in the code, so if there any way how to import it without giving a namespace or just import it (with require statement) without spl_autoload, it would be perfect. But I dont know how to do it. Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Don’t confuse folder structure with namespaces. The PSR4 standard encourages mapping of these two things, but PHP doesn’t care in any way. If you have a class with no namespace called `APIclient`, you are free to put it into folders as you see fit, it is just your responsibility to `require` it. If you just have two files, you can skip the autoloader and just require them manually.

Comment: @ChrisHaas The APIclient is a third party library so APIclient can have multiple files required in the code. So if I create a autoload_register inside my script the autoload will try also locate the thrird party classes also, and thats my problem. So in short my question is that how can I use autoload with third party libraries also in my code?

Comment: I'm assuming that the third party code doesn't have an autoloader of its own, but does it have a composer file at all? Another option you can do is just create an array of classes to files and stick that in your autoloader.

Comment: @ChrisHaas The third party app have its own autoloader, but in the documentation there are some comments about their own autoloader: Autoloader for Requests.. Register this with {@see register_autoloader()} if you'd like to avoid having to create your own. (You can also use `spl_autoload_register` directly if you'd prefer.)

Comment: At this point, without access to the third-party code I'm not sure what else to tell you. Is there a reason you don't want to use their autoloader?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I can use their autoloader its not problem at all but I need an own autoloader for my project (code) too. So I need to implement to my code their autoloader (if its possible somehow). Here is the their autoloader: [link](https://github.com/superfaktura/apiclient/blob/master/SFAPIclient/Requests.php) 
The question is that how can I run my own project with spl_autoload where is implemented their code. I dont know if its make any sense.

Comment: As long as you use `spl_autoload_register` you can have that multiple times, meaning one for your stuff and one for their stuff. The only problem will be if you have a class with the exact same fully qualified name which PHP does not have a way to resolve, the code itself needs to be changed. My recommendation would be to install this using composer and just require `__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'` from your root file, and then write an autoloader specific to your code which is ideally in a namespace of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found the answer to this question (But I'm not sure this is the best way to do it)

So in the spl_autoload I added an if is_file statement:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($path){
  $file_path = dirname(__DIR__, 2) . "/" . str_replace("\\", '/', $path) . '.php';
  if(is_file($file_path)){
    include_once $file_path;
  }
});
```

And in the Invoice.php file I require the API files with require statement:

```
require dirname(__DIR__, 1) . "/API/APIclient/APIclient.php";
```

And in this way I can use the object in the constructor:

```
public function __construct(){
  $this->apiSF = new \APIclient("XYZ", "XYZ"); 
}
```

But also if I print out the spl_autoload requested files $file_path variable in my case, there are a lot of files that do not exist (because of the API).